# .csv NOT loading when running exe file of project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, csv, visual-c++, exe

When I run my project in a Debugging environment, all the data point imported via .csv file are read properly. However, when I build the project and run the exe, the files are not read and the project runs as if all values are 0.

Do you know why this occurs?

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Comm and Windows 10 Home, latest updates.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you are using relative file names in your program, and thus depend on the current working directory. The current working directory is different when the project is run from inside the IDE, than when you run it standalone.

Comment: please give more details and add code snippets!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik How do you suggest to avoid that issue? Should I move the data files to the directory that contains the executable?

Comment: That would be one way, yes.